# agendaWeek: events not shown

Tags: fullcalendar

what I'm possibly doing wrong!?

I do NOT see my events when 'defaultView: agendaWeek' (or agendaDay).
PS: basicWeek (or basicDay) works just fine.

BUT: when clicking the 'month' view: ALL events are showing correctly in 'month' view! Then, when again clicking 'week' (or Day) I see them ALL correctly as agendaWeek (or agendaDay) view!

I'm running fullcalendar: 3.6.2

PS: sorry, posted same issue in non-related forum

must miss a stupid thing - thanks for your time and hints, ed

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
@if (Model.tagColorsEnabled && Model.tagColors != null) {
    <text>
            var tagSet = [
                @foreach (var tc in Model.tagColors)
                {
                    @Display(tc)
                }
            ];

            var tagIndex = [];
            for (var tag in tagSet) {
                tagIndex[tagSet[tag].slug] = tag;
            }

    </text>
}
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                locale: '@culture',
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',   //eddie  timeFormat: 'HH:mm{-HH:mm}', 
                slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',   //eddie  timeFormat: 'HH:mm{-HH:mm}', 
                // height: 500, //added by eddie
                // allDay: false,   // eddie
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
                    //  right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'  // eddie
                },
                    
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    var colors = { bg : event.defaultBackgroundColor, br: event.defaultBorderColor, fg: event.defaultTextColor };
@if (Model.tagColorsEnabled)
{
    <text>
                    var min = 100;
                    for (var klassNdx in event.className) {
                        var klass = event.className[klassNdx];
                        if (klass.substring(0, 4) === "tag-") {
                            var entry = tagIndex[klass.substring(4)];
                            if (entry !== undefined) {
                                if (entry < min) {
                                    colors = tagSet[entry];
                                    min = entry;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    </text>
}
                    $(element)
                        .css("background-color", colors.bg)
                        .css("color", colors.fg)
                        .css("border-color", colors.br);
                },
               
                editable: false,
                events: { 
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/_Calendar/" + Model.queryId)',
                },
               // defaultView: '@Model.defaultView',
                // defaultView: 'basicWeek',
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                weekends: @Model.showWeekends
                //viewRender: function (v, e) { alert("Rendering view"); }
                });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: without some sample event data it might be quite difficult to reproduce this. Can you show some sample event JSON data which can be used to demo the problem? I can't think of a reason, in normal use, why you would have a problem like this.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I certainly agree with your judgement - this code runs in OrchardCMS and I wouldn't know how to 
 e.g. us 'fiddle' to check. Well the amazing thing is that my 'eventRender: function (event ...' is showing ALL my events BUT only after I 
'click' the 'month' -> 'weeks' view (never uses the 'defaultView: 'agendaWeek' directly )'. Clearly I need to investigate more ... I was kind
of hoping that somebody experienced similar issues before ...

Comment: an addition: when defaultView: 'basicWeek' - I see all my events correctly in 'basicView' - clicking then 'Week' gives me the 'agendaView'

Comment: I wasn't asking for a JSfiddle necessarily, just some sample event JSON data (you can get it by watching your network tab for the ajax request which fetches them.

Comment: Thanks, you got me - a 70+ hobby developer!
you say '....watching your network tab for the ajax request...'. Is that in the DOM-> Network!?
Need some more guidance ... I know embarassing!

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools (press F12 in most browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, IE) and then click on the Network tab. Then load your page. All the files which are included in the page (JS, CSS etc) will load. Then if your page makes a request to the server to fetch the events (to the Calendar url), you'll see it listed. Then you can click on it. In the tabs which open to the right, see the "response" tab and you'll get the JSON it returned.

Comment: used the weekend to learn about JSON, Network, XHR ... and found

when 'defaultView: basicWeek'
{id: 16, start: "2017-11-09T08:00:00", end: "2017-11-09T09:00:00", allDay: false, title: "Sevent 1",…}

when 'defaultView: agendaWeek'
ExceptionMessage:"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I certainly do not change anyof the time formats in between!
Need to do some more tests
thanks again for your advise, ed

Comment: Hi, Didyou find resolution that issue  and How can you see error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" ? Where is it appears ? @edk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved - sort of!

When using 'defaultView: basicWeek / agendaWeek'; fact is that I get different DateTime info like:

basicWeek: '2017-1-06' --> which in turn works correctly!

agendaWeek:  '2017-1-06T00:00:00' --> which results in an error!

When stripping off 'T00:.....'  --> problem solved
I know that this is probably not the 'clean' solution BUT for the time being ..... will further check if time is available!
For now I like to thank ADyson for his advise and time spent.